# Read txt file and pass as a variable in url

Tags: python

Hi guys im new in python and i try to accomplish a task.
The task is the following i need to read a file called "ip.txt" and read line by line the file and pass the txt file lines to a URL using urlopen.

Here is my script

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

def send_alert():
    from smtplib import SMTP
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText

    msg = MIMEText('nuf said')
    msg['Subject'] = 'inventi.lt is unreachable'
    msg['From'] = 'XXX@xxxx.com'
    msg['To'] = 'jnin@xxxx.com'

    server = SMTP('mail.xxxxxx.com:2525')
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login('jnin@xxxxx.com', 'password')
    server.sendmail('jnin@xxxx.com', ['jnin@xxx.com'], msg.as_string())
    server.quit()

###### LEER FILE
ip_dirreciones = open("ip.txt", "r")

try:
    urlopen ('http://VARIABLE-HERE/cgi-bin/api-sys_operation?passcode=2000&request=REBOOT')

    print ("OK")
except:
    send_alert()
```

The idea is that the script will automatically run each line from the text file

sample

```
http://1.1.1.1/cgi-bin/api-sys_operation?passcode=2000&request=REBOOT
http://1.1.1.3/cgi-bin/api-sys_operation?passcode=2000&request=REBOOT
http://1.1.1.2/cgi-bin/api-sys_operation?passcode=2000&request=REBOOT
```

**UPDATE**

i make some progress but not working all the way. i just need to the script be able to read and use each line of the **ip.txt** file.

It only read the first line and then stop.
Here is the code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen


def send_alert():
    from smtplib import SMTP
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText

    msg = MIMEText('nuf said')
    msg['Subject'] = 'inventi.lt is unreachable'
    msg['From'] = 'email@email.com'
    msg['To'] = 'email@email.com'

    server = SMTP('mail.domain.com:2525')
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login('email@email.com', 'password!')
    server.sendmail('email@email.com', ['email@email.com'], msg.as_string())
    server.quit()

###### LEER FILE
f = open("ip.txt", "r")
for x in f:

 # print('http://'+ x +'/cgi-bin/api-sys_operation?passcode=2000&request=REBOOT')

try:
    urlopen ('http://'+ x +'/cgi-bin/api-sys_operation?passcode=2000&request=REBOOT')

    print ("OK")
except:
    send_alert()
```

Answer (score 2):

You read from files like such:

```
with open('ip.txt', 'r') as file:
    link_list = file.readlines()
```

This will create a list where every line of your `.txt` file is converted to an item within a list. You can then iterate through this list to use each item in turn!

If your question is about combining strings to make the links (as in your .txt file contains:

1. 1.1.1.1
2. 1.1.1.2
3. 1.1.1.3)

Then you would say:

```
for link in link_list:
    urlopen ('http://{}/cgi-bin/api-sys_operation?passcode=2000&request=REBOOT'.format(link))
```

This will dynamically fill in the `{}` with whatever `link` is that iteration

**@EDIT**

In your comment you say you have an error in your header at `b'192.168.0.77\n'` this is because you are giving your program a bunch of bytes when it expects a string. This can be avoided with:

```
urlopen ('http://{}/cgi-bin/api-sys_operation?passcode=2000&request=REBOOT'.format(link.decode('utf-8')))
```

Where the only difference is we `.decode()` it to a `utf-8` string!

Comment: the wear thing is that im not getting any error message in the console I'm getting the email that says that the url is not working.

**More Info** if the url is not reachable i get an email saying that.

Comment: @JoanNin it is not giving any error messages because you are catching them all. You have to remove the `try:` and `except:` for it to show you an error. Alternatively you can do `except Exception as e:`; `print(e)` to show the error it catches.

Comment: I'm getting this error `Invalid header value b'192.168.0.77\n'` we are getting closer

Comment: @JoanNin Why not try saving the URL in a variable as in `my_url = 'http://{}/cgi-bin/api-sys_operation?passcode=2000&request=REBOOT'.format(link)` and then follow it with `print(my_url)` so you can see what you are trying to open. Perhaps you don't need to decode it at all, and the `urlopen()` was encoding it before giving you the error message?

Comment: i make some progress but not working all the way. i just need to the script be able to read and use each line of the **ip.txt** file.

It only read the first line and then stop.

Comment: @JoanNin You must not not using my code. You need to use the first 2 lines of code from my post, and then you can immediately after put `for link in link_list:`; `print(link)` This will print every line from the file one after another. The error must be elsewhere in your code unfortunately